# How to design a command line interface (CLI) which accepts Python functions or code?

Tags: python, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have a function that parses a given string with specific rules. I would like to design a CLI interface for this function. But the problem is I want that a user should be able to call this function via CLI using a READER & WRITER function of its own. To make it clear, here is a sample code and a demonstration of what I'm trying to explain.

```py
# mylib.py
# piece of code that belongs to my lib
def parser(_id, text):
    # parse the text & do some magic
    return (_id, parsed_text)
```

```py
# user-side code
def reader():
   # read from a database
   # or file or network or who knows where
   yield (_id, text)
```

```py
# user-side code
def writer(_id, text):
   # write to somewhere
   return True # or false depends on write action
```

A sample call should be something like this:

```
$ python mylib.py --reader <something-that-I-dont-know>
```

I don't want to use `eval` tricks but also I want that the user should be flexible while passing data to my library. Does this possible? Or should I try another approach?

Comment: Assuming you can write `from mypackage.mymodule import reader` in Python then you might write `--reader mypackage.mymodule:reader` when calling the CLI. That's what gunicorn and I think celery do. You will still have to write the logic to handle that though.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly was the problem?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I haven't tried anything but I know that I could do this using `eval` (Parse `reader` option, import the module and call the reader function). However, it's just didn't make me feel the right way to go. @AlexHall I am not sure that I understand you correctly. Where should I write `from mypackage.mymodule import reader`? Reader & Writer function has to be provided by the user. And also the user should be able to pass these functions to my library via CLI.

Comment: The command line is available in your script as the `sys.argv` list.  Make sure you understand how the shell has already parsed and split the command line to produce this list.  Spaces and special characters affect that.  The line may require quotes to prevent splitting.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for the answer. Maybe it's not so clear in the post however I am asking much more complicated stuff than you described. Basically, I would like to register (or import) a foreign function (that is written by the user) into the library code via CLI.

Comment: The user defines the function in a `.py` file and places it somewhere it can be imported. Your script then simulates the import using [`import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) and `getattr` based on the passed argument.

Comment: The usual approach is to have the user import your module, and then pass data, and their own functions, to your functions.  They handle the CLI, not you.  There is a  `importlib` module that gives you more control over imports than the common `import ...` statement, but I haven't used it much.

Comment: Well, I'd like to provide both of CLI and library interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @AlexHall, I've come up with the following solution:

```py
import pathlib
import importlib.util


def load_module(filepath):
    module_path = pathlib.Path(filepath)
    abs_path = module_path.resolve()
    module_name = module_path.stem

    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, abs_path)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    return module
```

Using this function, I am be able to import any valid python module exists in the filesystem even if the module is not in the path.

Here is a sample usage:

```py
parser = make_parser(prog="tokenizer")
args = parser.parse_args()
module = load_module(args.writer) # if nothing is passed, default action defined in the parser
writer = module.writer
module = load_module(args.reader)
reader = module.reader
# do what you want to do with them
```